# How does the quantum foam idea interact with entropy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy

In [quantum foam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_foam), is the pair-production + annihilation cycle entropy-neutral? Or does it result in an increase in entropy?

If it is entropy-neutral, then does that mean each of the two processes (pair-production, and annihilation) are entropy-neutral? (otherwise there would be a violation of second law of thermodynamics?)

If it results in an increase in entropy, then does that mean that there can be no isolated system where entropy remains the same for a long time, since there can be no system free of this process and this process will always lead to an increase in entropy at some standard rate?

Comment: What is "the quantum foam idea"?

Comment: Updated with wiki link

Comment: a relevant review of quantum foam https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/10/4/441/htm